# Authentication required between MVC Controller and JavaScript Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am using a ASP.NET MVC application and for all the CRUD operations, I am calling the Controller Action methods from the Client Page through AJAX ( angular js service ).

Here I have used ASP.NET form authentication for my MVC Pages. But I want to authenticate each Ajax call as well ( to those Controller methods), that only the logged-in users can call the ajax service from the page. Please advise.

I have already used the [Authorize] in my controller method.

Comment: just like something $http.post("~/Home/About").

Comment: If you are putting [Authorize] attributes on the web service controller then it is participating in the normal MVC authentication (via the cookies that are automatically attached to the AJAX request).

Comment: This is I want to know, actually I am not in position to test the same.If it is , then work done.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
       <text>
       // call ajax
       </text>
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As I told, I am calling from a Angular Controller, above code can't be used